Calculating the mean and standard deviation from a normal distribution
I am interested in methods for finding the mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution. It is inspired by the following question that is part of the A-level maths course in England.

The random variable $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Given that $P(X>35)=0.025$ and $P(X<15)=0.1469$ find the value of $\mu$ and $\sigma$.

This can be solved using the relation $Z= \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma}$ to give two simultaneous equation. To be clear, I am confident in solving this using Z-values:
$1.9599=\frac{35-\mu}{\sigma}$ and $-1.0499=\frac{15-\mu}{\sigma}$
I have two questions about generalizing this method:

How do you decide on the 'best' values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ if there are more than two probabilities given? The problem being that the simultaneous equations can be solved pairwise to give different solutions.

Is this method used in statistics to estimate mean and standard deviation of a normal distribution. Naively, I would expect $\mu$ and $\sigma$ to be estimated by the mean and standard deviation of a sample of data.



Personally, I would solve this numerically.

@user2974951 Could you expand on this please? The only approach I can think of is solving each pairwise system and the taking some sort of average. Is that what you mean by numerically?

No I mean general purpose optimization, which in this case says mu and sigma are approx. $21.976060$ and $6.644994$. The optimization minimizes the loss of the sum of the two equations.

@user2974951 Thanks for your reply but i am not sure I understand what you mean by the 'loss of the sum of the two equations'

I'm fairly certain that the exercise wants you to set up the integrals from the gaussian pdf and solve for the parameters. Just an exercise on manipulating the integrals stemming from the pdf/cdf of a random variable.

@GuilhermeMarthe Thanks for your reply. I am actually confident solving the  exercise. I was curious about: 1. How the approach would generalize if there were multiple CDF values given. 2. When would this method be used in a practical setting?

Re practical setting: sometimes we wish to analyze data summarized by others that are available only in summary form.  One common method of summary is binning, whereby only counts of observations falling within predetermined intervals (or "bins") are provided.  The first duplicate concerns a common example (a five-letter summary) but explains how to set up and solve the maximum likelihood equations to estimate $(\mu,\sigma).$
